# How to reference a cell outside pgfplots-table?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have written a dynamic LaTeX table which includes data from an external file and computes a new column out of the existing columns according to some criteria. Now I want to reference the computed cells and write it to another `tikzpicture`. One problem is, that I am not able to name the table which I created with the import of data and `\pgfplotstabletypeset`.

For comparison, I have referenced an other table (`\mytable`) which I read with `\pgfplotstableread{testdatahead.dat}{\mytable}` where I can take data from the table and insert it in a text (in red). (It is the same data as in the main file).

Is there a way of referencing a cell or to address its components like in the second example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false} % bringt aber nichts...

% Berechung von Abzug, 30 (bei kleiner 9 Stunden) oder 45 Minuten (bei größer 9 Stunden)
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{vergleich}{2} {\pgfmathparse{(#1-#2)<9) ? (#1-#2-0.5) : (#1-#2-0.75)}}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    header=true,
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={ after row=\bottomrule },
    display columns/0/.style={column name={Monat}},
    display columns/1/.style={column name={Tag}},
    display columns/2/.style={column name={Anfang}, fixed},
    display columns/3/.style={column name={Ende}, fixed},
    display columns/4/.style={dec sep align, column name={Arbeitszeit}},
    display columns/5/.style={column name={Spalte}, fixed},
    create on use/newcol/.style={
      create col/expr={vergleich(\thisrow{3},\thisrow{2})}
    },
    columns/newcol/.style={string type},
       highlightrow/.style={
        postproc cell content/.append code={
           \count0=\pgfplotstablerow
            \advance\count0 by1
            \ifnum\count0=#1
            \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={\bfseries\color{red}}{}}
            \fi
        },
    },
    %% every first column/.style={column type/.add={|}{}},  % style the first column
    %% every last column/.style={column type/.add={}{|}},   % style the last column
    %% columns/.style = {column type/.add={|}{|}},  % style the designated column
       highlightrow={3},
    columns={0,1,2,3,newcol},
    outfile={zeitenout.dat}  % Aber nur al TeX-formatierte Tabelle
]{testdata.dat}\\

% This is working:
\pgfplotstableread{testdatahead.dat}{\mytable}

\pgfplotstablegetelem{2}{Monat}\of{\mytable}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\MM}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{2}{Tag}\of{\mytable}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\TT}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{2}{Anfang}\of{\mytable}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Anfang}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{2}{Ende}\of{\mytable}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ende}{\pgfplotsretval}

Im Monat {\MM}, am  \TT. Tag habe ich um {\Anfang} Uhr angefangen, bin um {\Ende} Uhr nach Hause gegangen.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Corrsponding dat-File "testdata.dat":

```
1 01 8 16
1 02 7 15
1 03 6 17
1 04 6 17.5
1 05 6 15.5
1 05 7 17
```

Comment: It would be really nice if you included the `.dat`-file(s) as well, that way we don't have to make that ourselves.

Comment: `\addplot table[x index=4,y expr={vergleich(\thisrow{3},\thisrow{2})}] {\loadedtable};`?

Comment: @Henri, i don´t really understand your proposal?

Comment: @Coliban I thought you wanted to plot the data in the table and this is how you could to it with `pgfplots`.

Comment: @Henri, as you can see in my original post, i´ve already plotted it.

Answer (score 1):

After some reading i found a way to name the table and use the \pgfplotstabletypeset command:

I have to read the table first with a different command and use the \pgfplotstabletypeset - command afterwards:

1. \pgfplotstableread{testdata.dat}\mytable
2. \pgfplotstabletypeset[....]\mytable

Everything else is working, except, in my case, i had to switch from the header name to indexes to access the table data from outside the table:

```
\pgfplotstablegetelem{2}{0}\of{\mytable}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\MM}{\pgfplotsretval}
```

With this command i can use the 3rd row in the first column of the table and then reference every element.

But now i have found out, while i can reference the data in a pgftable, i can´t read the data from  a (in pgfplotstabletypeset) newly created column. Therefore, i can reference the static data in a table, i can´t reference the new cells.

Comment: You might try \pgfplotstablecreatecol instead of [create on use].

Comment: @John, i didnt found any documentation on the net, just examples which are not applicable to my problem. Normaly "create on use" does the function. My problem is that "\thisrow" is apperently not working on calculated cells with "preproc/expr".

Comment: @JohnKormylo, yes, it is an other approach and it works.

Comment: You should be able to find the documentation on CTAN.  http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplotstable.pdf